# Combining several paths into one in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, path

I have drawn this pattern, combining various elements together. It is a pattern that will be a papercut design. As you can see some elements overlap.

Before turning into an SVG file I want the whole thing to be one image (1 path) instead of being loads of little elements. Is there a way to do this?

[[image: pattern]
Click for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S4aT.png)

Comment: I assume you actually want some of the overlaps to merge and others to actually "cut out" (the overlapping stems should merge and the centers of the flowers should cut out for example)... right?

Comment: Yes. i have never done anything like this before so not sure if i've messed it up from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy enough with a few Pathfinder commands...

1. Select all the paths you want to merge (excluding any paths you want to "cut out". The centers of the flowers, for example).
2. Hit "Unite" in the Pathfinder panel.

   [image]
3. Create a compound path from the result, this essentially gives you a single "path" (either *Object → Compound Path → Make* or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>). You should have something like this:

   [image]
4. Invert the selection (*Select → Inverse*) to select the paths you want to cut out and repeat the process of uniting and creating a compound path. You should now have two compound paths:

[image]

5. Make sure the path you want to cut out is on top, select both and hit "Minus Front" from the Pathfinder panel, then create a compound path again. You should be left with a single (compound) path:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try this tonight. I will let you know how I get on!

Comment: Hi I tried it on a couple of elements in the pattern and it came up saying - "the filter produced no results. Please select two overlapping paths" do you know what could be happening as my paths are certainly overlapping.